# xampp site access from outside jump to localhost when try to log in to the site

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, lan

My site is in:
Windows 7
Browser: Chrome
Use XAMPP v3.2.1
Framework: CodeIgniter

When I try to access my site from outside in same local area network
it allow me to go to login page.  Then when I try to access the site giving
user name and password

1. It jump to localhost
   (like: localhost/mysite)
2. Then I get "This webpage is not available" message.

I comment out "New XAMPP security concept" in httpd-xampp.conf file:

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
#<LocationMatch "^/(?i:    (?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-

#info))">
     #order deny,allow
     #Allow from all
     #Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
            #fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
            #fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16        
#        Require local
#ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#</LocationMatch>
```

No luck yet

Comment: If settings in your site is set `http://loclhost/mysite` as siteurl, you can't open the website with `http://192.168.0.1/mysite` from another computer. (Wordpress is the best example).

Comment: @Khay Thanks for the reply.  I use my IPv4 (192.168.X.X ) And I can access the login page. But when I try to login user name and Pword the site jump to localhost.  I could use username and pwd and access my site until Feb 14th. I did not change any code in the site

Comment: @Khay, You mean I should change http://localhost/mysite to http://localhost:(XX)/mysite.   XX can be 80 ?

Comment: Is it only happened when you login to your website? Can also look around other pages?

Comment: @Khay, Thanks. Yes, when ever I try to login to website it jump to localhost.  I can access to my login page.

Comment: Try to check the form action at your login form. Since it is redirected back to localhost, probably the form action is with `localhost`. If not, I would like to suggest you to check login function of the website.

Comment: @Khay, Thanks.  I will give it a try.  It works in the computer I developed. But only does not work when I try to access from another computer.

Comment: Ur welcome. I wish it will solved your problem ;)

Comment: Could not find the solution yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to set WordPress Address and Site Address using your local IP instead of localhost. Go to your WordPress Administration > Settings > General, change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) to replace localhost with your IP. Such as:

```
http://192.168.x.xxx/wordpress
```

Then use the new address in browser to open the site from local or LAN. It works for me.